# Zend_Form_Decorator_File how to

Tags: zend-framework

I'm a beginner with Zend. I have a little web site in which I can write articles for a community of users. For each article, the user is able to attach one or more file. I made a form to provide the ability to the admin to update an article.

I can display a list of input file for each file that were attached with the article.

Now I wish to diplay a link to the file on the right of my input file control.

I think I need to use decorator but I have a hard time finguring out how to make it work.

Any help on this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to use a [View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html) in conjunction with the [ViewHelper Decorator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.viewHelper) to append the link to your File element.

First, if you don't already have a helper path set up, add this to `application.ini`:

```
resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = "My/View/Helper/"
```

Then in your path (`library` folder works great), create the directory tree `My/View/Helper`.

Create the View Helper in the above directory, for the example I am calling it `Link`, so create `My/View/Helper/Link.php`

The contents of Link.php is:

```
<?php

class My_View_Helper_Link extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function link($name, $value, $attribs, $elOptions)
    {
        if (!isset($attribs['linkOpts']) || !is_array($attribs['linkOpts']))
            return '';

        $linkOpts = $attribs['linkOpts'];

        $link = (isset($linkOpts['href'])) ? $linkOpts['href'] : '';
        $text = (isset($linkOpts['text'])) ? $linkOpts['text'] : '';

        if ($link == '' || $text == '') return '';

        return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $link, htmlspecialchars($text));
    }
}
```

Now, when you create your element, all you need to do is add the `ViewHelper` decorator, and pass some link options.

```
$fileDecorators = array(
    'File',
    array('ViewHelper', array('helper' => 'link')), // Add ViewHelper decorator telling it to use our Link helper
    'Errors',
    array('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description')),
    array('HtmlTag',     array('class' => 'form-div')),
    array('Label',       array('class' => 'form-label', 'requiredSuffix' => '*'))
);

$this->addElement('file', 'file1', array(
    'label'      => 'File Upload:',
    'required'   => false,
    'decorators' => $fileDecorators,
    'validators' => array(
        /* validators here */
     ),
    'linkOpts' => array('href' => 'http://site.com/page/link',
                        'text' => 'This is the link text',
    ),
));
```

Now if you use that stack of decorators for your file elements, and provide `linkOpts` to the element, it will render the link after the File input.  If no `linkOpts` are provided, or the `href` or `text` element then no link will be output after the File element.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rob Allen has written a great article on using Zend_Form, and runs through a good decorator example. Maybe this will help.

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/simple-zend_form-example/